# NullPointerException while retrieving values from EditTexts

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, logcat

I'm trying to insert values to a column called "id_usuario", so in my login page I got a method that is called in my button as an onclick event, here's the code:

```
public void logar(View view) {
        String login = edtlogin.getText().toString();
        String senha = edtlogin.getText().toString();

        LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO();

        loginDTO.setUsuario(login);
        loginDTO.setSenha(senha);

        new LoadingAsync().execute();
    }
```

This is the code for LoginDTO where I have the getter's and setter's for "usuario" and "senha":

```
public class LoginDTO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1111108194849414002L;

    private String usuario;
    private String senha;

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```

To insert data into the table "transacoes" I got this:

```
public void cadastrarTransacao(View view) {
        TransacaoDTO transacaoDTO = new TransacaoDTO();
        LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO();

        //int idUsuario = Integer.parseInt(activity.getIDUsuario(loginOpenHelper));

        transacaoDTO.setDesc(edtDescricao.getText().toString());
        transacaoDTO.setData(edtData.getText().toString());
        transacaoDTO.setValor(Long.parseLong(edtValor.getText().toString()));
        transacaoDTO.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(loginOpenHelper.getIDUsuario(loginDTO.getUsuario(), loginDTO.getSenha())));

        ValidacaoMock resultado = mockBO.cadastrarOperacao(transacaoDTO);

        MensagemUtil.addMsg(this, resultado.getMensagem());

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MockListActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
```

And for the "getIDUsuario" method:

```
public String getIDUsuario(String usuario, String senha){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String id = "id_usuario";

        String[] columns = {id};
        String[] selectionArgs ={usuario, senha};

        Cursor cursor = db.query("usuarios", columns, "nome_usuario=? AND senha=?", selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            int index0 = cursor.getColumnIndex(id);
            int idUsuario = cursor.getInt(index0);
            buffer.append(idUsuario);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

This is the error:

```
11-16 14:40:25.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10623): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-16 14:40:25.624: E/AndroidRuntime(10623):    at com.br.texapp.MockTransacaoActivity.cadastrarTransacao(MockTransacaoActivity.java:51)
```

The line which contains the error is this:

```
transacaoDTO.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(loginOpenHelper.getIDUsuario(loginDTO.getUsuario(), loginDTO.getSenha())));
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Have you initialized this loginOpenHelper ?

Comment: How do I do that? I'm starting right now in this Android world

Comment: Don't know to initialize the views or the class

Comment: What is loginOpenHelper? it looks like it's null

Comment: loginOpenHelper is the class where I have the "getIDUsuario" method and the sql to create my tables

Comment: @MikeOliveira see my answer it should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that you have not created the object `loginOpenHelper`. I bet this is throwing NPE.

Something like

```
loginOpenHelper = new LoginOpenHelper();
```

Comment: public class MockTransacaoActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 EditText edtDescricao = null;
 EditText edtData = null;
 EditText edtValor = null;
 
 private MockBO mockBO;
 private LoginOpenHelper loginOpenHelper;

Comment: @MikeOliveira Write this also in `onCreate` after setcontentView `loginOpenHelper = new LoginOpenHelper();`. By declaring variable doesn't mean that you created a object of it.

Comment: it asks me for the context, should I put "this"?

Comment: you talked about the views, how do I initalize them, cause I'm getting a different error right now

Comment: Can we chat somewhere here?

Comment: @MikeOliveira No we can't because you have only 4 reputation. For chat you require at least 20 reputation.